# Securing API key in React SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api-key

I am a new developer. I have a React SPA deployed on Firebase that queries Google’s Geocoding and Time Zone APIs. I cannot restrict access based on HTTP referrers/domain names because these APIs are web service APIs and have to be restricted based on IP address. However, there does not seem to be a way to get the IP address of a Firebase app.

So my question is, are there alternative approaches to using and securing API keys in my app? I am particularly interested in approaches that leverage any inbuilt capabilities of React or Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

An IP restricted API is supposed to only be used in server-side applications.
I suppose you should configure your key restrictions for Android/iOS apps:

[image: Google Console Key Settings screen]